# is it safe to unsubscribe while consuming reaches some condition?

Tags: spring-rabbit

i want to end subscribe a queue while consuming.

but my ack mode is AcknowledgeMode.AUTO, the container will issue the ack/nack based on whether the listener returns normally, or throws an exception.

so, if i unsubscribed in the consume method, then the method returns, and container try to ack, but it already unsubscribed before, so what would happens, is it safe to do so as follows:

#### unsubscribe way 1

```
        DirectMessageListenerContainer container = getContainer();
        container.setMessageListener(message -> {
            // do something with message

            // if some condition reaches, unsubscribe
            if (reachEnd()) {
                container.removeQueueNames(message.getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue());
            }
        });
```

#### unsubscribe way 2

```
        container.setMessageListener(new ChannelAwareMessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {
                // do something with message

                // if some condition reaches, unsubscribe
                if (reachEnd()) {
                    channel.basicCancel(message.getMessageProperties().getConsumerTag());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do neither, stop the container instead. Either way causes the consumer to be cancelled.

You should call stop() on a new thread, not the listener thread - it would cause a deadlock.

Comment: you mean i could cancel in listener's onMessage method with a new thread like below ?
`new Thread(() -> container.removeQueueNames(...)).start()`

Comment: No; you should call `container.stop()` instead, from another thread, canceling the consumer will prevent the ack from being sent.

Comment: `container.stop()` will cancel all. i'm consuming hundreds queues, and only needs to cancel some while some condition meets, not cancal all.
i find that `container.setAdviceChain()` is the right thing

Comment: Then you should use separate containers for each queue. The framework is not designed to cover this use case. It is not clear how the advice chain can help.